# Show that the tensor $B_{ik} = ε_{ijk}a_j$ is antisymmetric

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

> Show that the tensor $B_{ik} = ε_{ijk}a_j$ is antisymmetric

This is a calculation for an applied mathematics over mechanics course, so we're working over $\mathbb R^3$ generally, just to note.

$$B_{ik} = ε_{ijk}a_j = -ε_{kji}a_j = -B_{ik} $$

Is it as simple as that ?

Comment: You mean $\cdots=-B_{ki}$, but yes, it is that simple.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown It was a "thorough" example stated by a leaflet we have and I doubted it would be that straightforward. What goes in-between there ? I'm asking cause I actually wanted to understand the calculations.